# 'Zero out' a matrix using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, matrix, complexity

Below is my code for an attempted solution to cracking the coding interview exercise 1.8 written in python 3.5.  The problem statement is:

> Write an algorithm such that if an element in an MxN matrix is 0, its entire row and column are set to 0.

I looked at the hints for this problem so I do know that my solution is not the most space efficient possible.  I believe the time complexity of the code below is \$O(M*N)\$ and the space complexity is \$O(M + N)\$.  I wrote small unit tests to test my code.  Looking for feedback on what needs to be improved, especially in terms of readability.

```
import unittest


def locate_zero_rows(matrix: list) -> list:
    """Given an NxM matrix find the rows that contain a zero."""
    zero_rows = [False for _ in range(len(matrix))]
    for row_num, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for col_num, element in enumerate(row):
            if element == 0:
                zero_rows[row_num] = True
    return zero_rows


def locate_zero_cols(matrix: list) -> list:
    """Given an NxM matrix find the columns that contain a zero."""
    zero_cols = [False for _ in range(len(matrix[0]))]
    for row_num, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for col_num, element in enumerate(row):
            if element == 0:
                zero_cols[col_num] = True
    return zero_cols


def zero_out(matrix: list) -> list:
    """Given an NxM matrix zero out all rows and columns that contain at least one zero."""
    zero_rows, zero_cols = locate_zero_rows(matrix), locate_zero_cols(matrix)

    for row_num, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for col_num, element in enumerate(row):
            if zero_rows[row_num] or zero_cols[col_num]:
                matrix[row_num][col_num] = 0
    return matrix


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_locate_zero_rows(self):
        matrix = [[5, 3, 2, 1],
                  [-3, 0, 5, 0],
                  [0, -1, 2, 6]]
        zero_rows = [False, True, True]
        self.assertSequenceEqual(locate_zero_rows(matrix), zero_rows)

    def test_locate_zero_cols(self):
        matrix = [[5, 3, 2, 1],
                  [-3, 0, 5, 0],
                  [0, -1, 2, 6]]
        zero_cols = [True, True, False, True]
        self.assertSequenceEqual(locate_zero_cols(matrix), zero_cols)

    def test_zero_out(self):
        matrix = [[5, 3, 2, 1],
                  [-3, 0, 5, 0],
                  [0, -1, 2, 6]]
        zeroed_out_matrix = [[0, 0, 2, 0],
                             [0, 0, 0, 0],
                             [0, 0, 0, 0]]
        self.assertSequenceEqual(zero_out(matrix), zeroed_out_matrix)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Is numpy not allowed?

Comment: The problem does not say you can not use numpy.  I am solving these problems to learn programming and to prepare for technical interviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big issue I can see is that you search every element.  You don't need to do this, you only need to check if `0` is anywhere in that row or column.  You can use the `in` operation to test this.  It will short-circuit after the first `0` is found, avoiding having to search the entire row or column.  This won't reduce the time complexity, but will improve the best-case performance considerably.

Second, you can use `zip` to switch between rows and columns.

Third, you can reduce that check to a simple list comprehension, generator expression, or generator function.

Fourth, you can use `~all` to detect if there are any zeros in a given sequence.  This is slightly faster than `in`.

Finally, since you are making the changes in-place, you don't need to return the modified matrix.

So here is my version:

```
import unittest


def locate_zero_rows(matrix: list) -> list:
    """Given an NxM matrix find the rows that contain a zero."""
    return [i for i, row in enumerate(matrix) if not all(row)]


def locate_zero_cols(matrix: list) -> list:
    """Given an NxM matrix find the columns that contain a zero."""
    return locate_zero_rows(zip(*matrix))


def zero_out(matrix: list) -> None:
    """Given an NxM matrix zero out all rows and columns that contain at least one zero."""
    zero_rows = locate_zero_rows(matrix)
    zero_cols = locate_zero_cols(matrix)
    ncol = len(matrix[0])
    for rowi in zero_rows:
        matrix[rowi] = [0]*ncol
    for coli in zero_cols:
        for row in matrix:
            row[coli] = 0


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_locate_zero_rows(self):
        matrix = [[5, 3, 2, 1],
                [-3, 0, 5, 0],
                [0, -1, 2, 6]]
        zero_rows = [1, 2]
        self.assertSequenceEqual(locate_zero_rows(matrix), zero_rows)

    def test_locate_zero_cols(self):
        matrix = [[5, 3, 2, 1],
                [-3, 0, 5, 0],
                [0, -1, 2, 6]]
        zero_cols = [0, 1, 3]
        self.assertSequenceEqual(locate_zero_cols(matrix), zero_cols)

    def test_zero_out(self):
        matrix = [[5, 3, 2, 1],
                [-3, 0, 5, 0],
                [0, -1, 2, 6]]
        zeroed_out_matrix = [[0, 0, 2, 0],
                            [0, 0, 0, 0],
                            [0, 0, 0, 0]]
        zero_out(matrix)
        self.assertSequenceEqual(matrix, zeroed_out_matrix)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

You can improve this further by making the column list comprehension a expression.  I think this will give this a `O(M)` space complexity:

```
def zero_out(matrix: list) -> None:
    """Given an NxM matrix zero out all rows and columns that contain at least one zero."""
    zero_cols = (i for i, col in enumerate(zip(*matrix)) if not all(col))
    zero_rows = [i for i, row in enumerate(matrix) if not all(row)]
    ncol = len(matrix[0])
    for coli in zero_cols:
        for row in matrix:
            row[coli] = 0
    for rowi in zero_rows:
        matrix[rowi] = [0]*ncol
```

You can't make both comprehensions with this structure because changes to one would be reflected in the other.

It is possible to make both comprehensions using `itertools.zip_longest`, but you don't gain any space complexity (at least for matrices where `N` and `M` are similar), and it hurts your performance.

If you can use numpy, this can be simplified enormously:

```
import numpy as np
import unittest


def zero_out(matrix: np.array) -> None:
    """Given an NxM matrix zero out all rows and columns that contain at least one zero."""
    zero_cols = ~matrix.all(axis=0)
    zero_rows = ~matrix.all(axis=1)
    matrix[:, zero_cols] = 0
    matrix[zero_rows, :] = 0


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_zero_out(self):
        matrix = np.array([[5, 3, 2, 1],
                           [-3, 0, 5, 0],
                           [0, -1, 2, 6]])
        zeroed_out_matrix = np.array([[0, 0, 2, 0],
                                      [0, 0, 0, 0],
                                      [0, 0, 0, 0]])
        zero_out(matrix)
        np.testing.assert_array_equal(matrix, zeroed_out_matrix)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Edit: added `~all`.
Edit 2: Add numpy
Edit 3: use `not all` instead of `~all`

Comment: Why do we need two for rowi loops?

Comment: @newToProgramming: typo, sorry, fixed

Comment: `~all(row)` isn't a good idea.  ~ is a bitwise not, not a logical not, and since True == 1, ~True == -2, meaning that `bool(True) == bool(~True) == True`.

Comment: @DSM Good catch, fixed

Answer (score 1):

#### Repetition

I would write only one function to locate zeros:

```
def locate_zeros(matrix: IntegerMatrix) -> Iterable[Position]:
    """Given an NxM matrix find the positions that contain a zero."""
    for row_num, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for col_num, element in enumerate(row):
            if element == 0:
                yield (col_num, row_num)
```

And use it in `zero_out` like this:

```
    if row_num in (x[1] for x in zeros_positions) or col_num in (x[0] for x in zeros_positions):
        matrix[row_num][col_num] = 0
```

#### Type hints

Given that you specifically mentioned Python 3.5 and that you already have something like type hints on your functions, I suggest you go all the way with [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) compatible type hints.

```
from typing import List, Any,  Iterable, Tuple

Position = Tuple(int, int)
IntegerMatrix = List[List[int]]

def locate_zeros(matrix: IntegerMatrix) -> Iterable[Position]:

def zero_out(matrix: IntegerMatrix) -> IntegerMatrix:
```

This way you can statically check your code has the correct types like in natively statically types languages and give the user much more detailed information on the types.

Comment: thank you.  I will try and understand the space and time complexity of your implementation of locate_zeros, I assume it is O(1) space O(m*n) time?  Though in retrospect i should have combined the two functions into one even without implementing it as a generator I assume.

Comment: What is `zeros_positions`?

Comment: @vnp locate_zeros in the matrix